# c++ cstring find and replace

Tags: c++, replace, find, c-strings

I have a C++ project (Microsoft Visual C++ 2008) that was developed years ago by a colleague of mine and I need to update something.

I have a CString that contains a json and I need to find and replace every combination of 4 consecutive numbers that is present with ****.

Example string

1234567 12 34 78 iioi78ccc8888 aaassd dededeed ed

Resulting string

****567 12 34 78 iioi78ccc**** aaassd dededeed ed

Can you suggest a function that can effectively do this, that is fully compatible with Microsoft Visual C++ 2008.

Thank you.

P.S. My approach would be to use RegEX to find the list of 4 consecutive digits and to replace them but support for Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 is limited – as I was reading.

Comment: @Ron Op's asking for a function (presumably in the standard library) though.

Comment: In that case it is unclear what the question is.

Comment: all you need is `operator[]`. I dont see the problem...

Comment: Considering the VS version (2008) and the CString existing implementation - I was looking for a CString (based) search an replace function.

Comment: There are no regular expression searches and replaces in CString of Visual C++ 2008 if you were looking for that.

Comment: I was reading about this nonexisting feature that is why I need something similar done with CString. Considering that the development environment is 10 years old - I was thinking that someone did something like this in the past and might give me a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty trivial to write manually:

```
const int DIGIT_COUNT = 4;
int length = strlen(input);
int consecutiveDigits = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
   if (isDigit(input[i]))
     consecutiveDigits++;
   else
     consecutiveDigits = 0;

   if (consecutiveDigits == DIGIT_COUNT)
     for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
       input[i - j] = '*';
}
```

Add an `isDigit(char)` function and you're good.

Comment: After briefly reading the `CString` documentation, I don't think there is any better way of achieving the goal. This function is a small and simple solution

Comment: Yes. I agree with that. The sample code logic is fine - I need to adjust it to CString since the conversion of strings can be problematic.

Comment: Huh, I trusted the `c-string` tag and assumed we were talking about classic C-strings. I now learned that the `CString` in question is actually a framework class.

Comment: Yes is told old CString but I have managed to make it work. Thank you :)